# Hibernate could not load SchemaDropperImpl

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee

I am using TomEE 8.0.0.M1 microprofile ,Hibernate,Arquillian and HsqlDB for POC. trying to use latest hibernate version 5.3.7.Final. After arquillian war deployment,  server starts then immediately I am getting **Could not load [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl$JdbcContextDelayedDropImpl** and server stops.

But real time I am not getting this exception, why while unit test I am getting this exception.

**Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

<persistence-unit name="MICRO_DS" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>mpdatasource</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.demo.entity.UserDE</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

**Arquillian.xml**

```
<extension qualifier="persistence">
    <property name="defaultDataSource">openejb:Resource/mpdatasource</property>
    <property name="defaultTransactionMode">COMMIT</property>
    <property name="defaultCleanupPhase">NONE</property>
</extension>

<container qualifier="tomee" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="classifier">microprofile</property>
        <property name="version">8.0.0-M1</property>
        <property name="httpPort">-1</property>
        <property name="stopPort">-1</property>
        <property name="ajpPort">-1</property>
        <property name="dir">target/apache-tomee-remote</property>
        <property name="appWorkingDir">target/arquillian-test-working-dir</property>
        <property name="properties">
                        mpdatasource=new://Resource?type=DataSource
                        mpdatasource.JdbcDriver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
                        mpdatasource.JdbcUrl=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test
                        mpdatasource.UserName=sa
                        mpdatasource.Password=
                        mpdatasource.JtaManaged=true
                        mpdatasource.LogSql=true
        </property>     
    </configuration>
</container>
```

**StackTrace**

```
Nov 30, 2018 12:20:36 PM org.apache.openejb.client.EventLogger log
INFO: RemoteInitialContextCreated{providerUri=http://localhost:44077/tomee/ejb}
30-Nov-2018 12:20:37.010 INFO [http-nio-44077-exec-8] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: /home/project/target/arquillian-test-working-dir/0/test
30-Nov-2018 12:20:37.327 INFO [http-nio-44077-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl$JdbcContextDelayedDropImpl]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl$JdbcContextDelayedDropImpl]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1176)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl.perform(SchemaDropperImpl.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:815)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.close(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:255)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2526)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.undeploy(DeployerEjb.java:445)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer._invoke(SingletonContainer.java:272)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer.invoke(SingletonContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:371)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:360)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:247)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:104)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
30-Nov-2018 12:20:38.309 SEVERE [http-nio-44077-exec-8] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication undeployException original cause
 java.lang.Exception: persistence-unit: MICRO_DS -1586006982localhost: org/hibernate/tool/schema/internal/SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl$JdbcContextDelayedDropImpl
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2530)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.DeployerEjb.undeploy(DeployerEjb.java:445)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.security.internal.InternalSecurityInterceptor.invoke(InternalSecurityInterceptor.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer._invoke(SingletonContainer.java:272)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.singleton.SingletonContainer.invoke(SingletonContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:371)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:360)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:247)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:104)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/tool/schema/internal/SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl$JdbcContextDelayedDropImpl
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl.perform(SchemaDropperImpl.java:526)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.close(SessionFactoryImpl.java:815)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.close(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:255)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2526)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl$JdbcContextDelayedDropImpl]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1319)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1176)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl$JdbcContextDelayedDropImpl]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1329)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
    ... 59 more
Nov 30, 2018 12:20:38 PM org.apache.openejb.arquillian.common.TomEEContainer undeploy
```

Comment: Are you or the frameworks you're using perhaps setting a different value for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` during the unit tests than is used in production?  For example, is there a local config file in the prod env ?

Comment: OR, if you're deploying to a container, perhaps the container is providing some of the Hibernate dependencies and those are needed in the test context.  If you're using Maven or gradle or similar, you can mark the dependencies accordingly so they are available in the test env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have included hibernate entitymanager jar in Arquillian WebArchive and added org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.class in War bundle. issue is resolved.

```
 PomEquippedResolveStage pomEquippedResolveStage = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("pom.xml");

        File[] hibernateLibs = pomEquippedResolveStage.resolve(
                "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager"
                 ).withTransitivity().asFile(); 
 final WebArchive webArchive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addAsLibraries(hibernateLibs)                
             .addClass(org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.class)
```